# Text scaling / clipboard issue

Tags: fonts, vim, png, dia

I am having some difficulty understanding some issues with dia, perhaps better posted as two questions, however I do get the impression that they are related in gnome somehow; they are as follows:

1. When I copy text to the system clipboard from vim, it is not readable by the paste function in dia.
2. When I output a .png file from dia, the characters of each line appear piled up on top of each other. Whilst writing this question, I have created a a small file to demonstrate the issue and I now see that the text is spaced correctly excepting that it is of the wrong length; there would appear to be a translation issue in the font scaling, or something similar.

   [image]

Why is this?
How can I export the text into the png files in a more predictable way?

Thank you for your generous consideration and for any eventual assistance.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer to my own question, I will leave it to the moderators discretion as to whether or not to delete these posts.

Within the dia preferences there is an option for the preferred png translator; the default is called `cairo PNG` the issue is solved by using `Pixbuf[png]`. Apparently I need to learn more about the use and options of the system bus to understand the copy paste behaviour.

Thank you for your time if you are reading this.